# how i can skip won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: service, playback

I have downgrade Google play services to 12.2.21 when I tried to open any google app message appears " won't run unless you update google play services " 
how I can skip the update and use google apps

*note*
I'm not a programmer or an android Professional user